# Bash: Loop through lines of a file and assign line to numbered variable names

Tags: bash, eval

I intend to read the lines of a short .txt file and assign each line to variables containing the line number in the variable name.

File example.txt looks like this:

```
Line A
Line B
```

When I run the following code:

```
i=1
while read line; do
  eval line$i="$line"
  echo $line
  ((i=i+1))
done < example.txt
```

What I would expect during execution is:

```
Line A
Line B
```

and afterwards being able to call

```
$ echo $line1
Line A
$ echo $line2
Line B
```

However, the code above results in the error:

```
-bash: A: command not found
```

Any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote-removal happens twice with `eval`.  Your double-quotes are getting removed before `eval` even runs.  I'm not even going to directly answer that part, because there are better ways to do this:

```
readarray line < example.txt  # bash 4
echo "${line[0]}"
```

Or, to do exactly what you were doing, with a different variable for each line:

```
i=1
while read line$((i++)); do
    :
done < example.txt
```

Also check out `printf -v varname "%s" value` for a better / safer way to assign by reference.

Check out the bash-completion code if you want to see some complicated call-by-reference bash shenanigans.

Addressing your comment: if you want to process lines as they come in, but still save previous lines, I'd go with this construct:

```
lines=()
while read l;do
    lines+=( "$l" )
    echo "my line is $l"
done < "$infile"
```

This way you don't have to jump through any syntactic hoops to access the current line (vs. having to declare a reference-variable to line$i, or something.)

Bash arrays are really handy, because you can access a single element by value, or you can do `"${#lines[@]}"` to get the line count.  Beware that `unset lines[4]` leaves a gap, rather than renumbering `lines[5:infinity]`.  See the "arrays" section in the bash man page.  To find the part of the manual that documents `$#` expansion, and other stuff, search in the manual for `##`.  The Parameter Expansion section is the first hit for that in the bash 4.3 man page.

Comment: -bash: readarray: command not found (OSX)
Also, I would like to do some stuff while looping over the lines, like an if to check line number, and assign other variables depending on line. How would I do that?

Comment: OS X apparently uses an ancient version of bash.  `readarray` doesn't do anything special; it's just somewhat faster than a `read` / append loop.

Answer (score 1):

`eval line$i="$line"` tells bash to evaluate the string "line1=Line A", which attempts to invoke a command named A with the environment variable "line1" set to the value of Line.  You probably want to do `eval "line$i='$line'"`